# Given the solution of $Ax=b$ for some $b$ finding the nullspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

So i have 2 questions. First of all, we know that everything of the form $p+$ nullspace vector is a solution to $Ax=b$ when $Ap=b$. Now my first question is, how do we know these are all the solutions. I figured that the dimension of solutions of $Ax=b$ must be the same as the nullspaces (number of free variables) and so our solution already has the proper dimension ( guess 2? actually not sure about that), so there cannot be more solutions.

Another question is a consequences of that. Say i solved the equation of $Ax=b$ and got $c$ + some span of vectors. Can i conclude that that span is actually nullspace? I think so but i am not sure.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, Let $\{v \in \text{nul}(A)\}$ be any solution $Av=0$ to the homogeneous equation of $Ax=b$, and let $p$ be a particular solution for $Ap=b$.

Using a little algebra, we can see that $A(p + v) = Ap + Av = b + 0 = b$.

This proves we can get at least ONE other solution from a particular solution, but how can we prove it for all solutions?

Let $p'$ be another solution to $Ax=b$, then

$Ap = b = Ap' \implies A(p' − p) = b − b = 0$

Which implies that the difference of two particular solutions gives us the homogeneous solution. In other words, every solution is equal to the sum of a particular solution and a homogeneous solution, which also answers your second question. You are correct with your assumption.